# Implement a constructor / destructor like functionality for methods

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm building a simple (unit) test framework where a user can test a certain functionality.

But now i need to have a `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` functionality. I'm just not sure how to implement this.

My code looks something like this:

```
class TestCase
{
    public function SetUp ( ) { }
    public function TearDown ( ) { }

    // Down here are alot of assertion methods
    public function AssertTrue ( )
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function AssertFalse( )
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Another class then extends this class:

```
class SomeTestCase extends TestCase
{
    public function SetUp ( )
    {
        echo 'SetUp';
    }

    public function TearDown ( )
    {
        echo 'SetUp';
    }

    public function TestMethod1 ( )
    {
        // do some test
    }

    public function TestMethod2 ( )
    {
        // do some other test
    }
}
```

Now the `SetUp()` method needs to run on the start of every test method. So in this case `TestMethod1` and `TestMethod2`.

The `TearDown()` method needs to run at the end of every test method.

But how can i do this from the `TestCase` class. I don't want it to be so that a user needs to add `$this->SetUp()` and `$this->TearDown()` manually in every method.

I want it to act like a sort of `__construct`, `__destruct` but then for each method.

How can i do this?

Comment: As a possible solution, you can create some wrapper which will always run `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods during test cases execution.

Comment: You do know that [this wheel has already been invented](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/)?

Comment: Not tested it, but something like this should work: http://codepad.org/w40NTDNu

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to hardcode `setup()` into all of your methods, which is idiotic, or have a single entry point that is not one of the test methods. So what immediately comes to mind is have a trigger method that accepts as a parameter the name of the class you or your users are looking to execute. For example:

```
public function trigger($method){
    $this->SetUp();
    $this->$method;
}
```

You get the method name from the magic function `__call`

```
public function __call($method){
    $this->trigger($method);
}
```

And as you might have already figured, you can't have classes with the same name as their 'call' name because that way `__call` will never execute. You need to set up a relation between the method name that you want to be called and a dummy name that no one will know.

```
private $methodRelations = array(
    'testMethod1' => 'dummyMethod1',
    'testMethod2' => 'dummyMethod2'
)
```

Then the whole class would look like

```
class TestCase{
    private $methodRelations = array(
        'testMethod1' => 'dummyMethod1',
        'testMethod2' => 'dummyMethod2'
    )

    public function __call($method){
        $this->trigger($this->methodRelations[$method]);
    }

    public function trigger($method){
        $this->SetUp();
        $this->$method;
    }

    public function dummyMethod1( )
    {
        // do some test
    }

    public function dummyMethod2( )
    {
        // do some test
    }
}
```

And for even neater look you can combine `trigger` with `__call` but for the purpose of better understanding I left them apart. Good luck!

Comment: The `TestCase` class also contains the Assertions? I need the abstraction. I don't think this will work out for me